# Using Spring to wire directly a concrete class

Tags: spring

Does it makes sense in Spring to use @Autowired to wire directly to a concrete class and not to an interface (and make use of 'by type' autowiring)

If a class doesn't implements an interface wouldn't it be better to instantiate it via constructor or a factory (keeping things simple); rather than make it a Spring bean just for the heck of it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Does it makes sense in Spring to use `@Autowired` to wire directly to a concrete class and not to an interface

Sure. The practice of autowiring is independent of *what* you're autowiring. It'll work with classes just as well as interfaces.

However, whether or not it's a good idea is debatable, although this is a more general question of whether you should always introduce an interface for a given class, rather than talk directly to the class type.  The benefits include easier unit-testing and a cleaner design, at the expense of code clutter.

There's another good reason to autowire interface types rather than class types, which is that if Spring needs to generate a proxy object around the bean before injecting it, then if the bean's class defines *any* interfaces, then the proxy will implement those interfaces, and will *not* be type-compatible with the bean class itself. If you then try and autowire that bean by class type, it will fail. The easiest way to avoid this annoying scenario is to always autowire by interface type, that way it will lways work as you expect.

> and make use of 'by type' autowiring

If you mean [container-level `byType` autowiring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire), then you don't want to do that. It's the old Spring 1.x style of autowiring, and it's highly inflexibile (see [limitations of autowiring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-exceptions)).

Stick with `@Autowired`, it's much more flexible and easier to control.

> If a class doesn't implements an interface wouldn't it be better to instantiate it via constructor or a factory (keeping things simple); rather than make it a Spring bean just for the heck of it.

The two questions are completely separate. An object should be made a Spring bean if you need Spring to control its dependencies and lifecycle, regardless of whether or not it implements interfaces.  If you find that the object has no dependencies, and no meaningful interface, then perhaps there is no reason to make it a bean.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to decide if hardwiring this dependency into other classes is ok.  For instance, how many different classes are likely to require this dependency?  If the answer is many then you will be creating many instances of this class where only one is required.

Also, what dependancies does this concrete class have?  You will have to configure those inside the class that depends on it.

The object of [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) is to reduce the dependencies between classes and make your code loosely coupled.