# Spring @Autowire Bean constructor NoSuchBeanDefinitionException Hibernate Service

Tags: hibernate, spring, constructor, javabeans, autowired

I have the following error, when I try to Autowire my Bean constructor:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [dimensionmanagement.service.DimensionService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:920)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:789)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723)
>       ... 89 more

I have defined the dimensionmanagement.service.DimensionService like that:

```
@Service @Transactional public class DimensionService implements Serializable {
```

in my applicationContext.xml :

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="dimensionmanagement" />
```

if any more questions please ask!
Thanks Jonas

Comment: Have you annotated the class that you are trying to Autowire as a Component(@Component) or a similar annotation??

Comment: yes, its annotated as `@Component("managementBean")
@Scope("session")
public class ManagementBean implements Serializable {`

Comment: How are you loading your context? Is this a web app?

Comment: It makes no sense to have a @Transactional @Service bean marked as `Serializable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be autowiring interface and not a class. `DimensionService` should be an interface. Create a class `DimensionServiceImpl` by implementing `DimensionService`

If you want continue using **class** read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288153/using-spring-to-wire-directly-a-concrete-class/5288632#5288632) on how to do it.

Comment: Im not sure if this solved the error, but i should really have dont that before, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you need

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.whatever.mypackage" />
```

Comment: y quite sure, bean is in dimensionmanagement.view, service in dimensionmanagement.service.