# Autowiring interface vs class

Tags: spring, autowired

If there are more than one implementation of an interface, then I would have to use @Qualifier to indicate which class I want to autowire with. Wouldn't it make more sense to autowire the class directly instead of interface?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Spring to wire directly a concrete class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288153/using-spring-to-wire-directly-a-concrete-class)

Comment: I get the idea behind OOP principles and why using Interface is better than concrete implementations, but it doesnt answer my question. Why would I Autowire an interface with say 2 implementations when I will be forced to use Qualifier to specify which class should be called, when I can directly use Autowired on the implementing class itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is what object oriented programming (especially abstraction and polymorphism) is about.

You build the classes independendent of concrete implementations and use an interface.

This allows you to change what implementation you use at any point.

Assume you have this:

```java
public interface I{
    void doSomething();
}

@Component("a")
public class A implements I{
    public void doSomething(){
        //...
    }
    public void doSomethingElse(){
        //...
    }
}
@Component("b")
public class B implements I{
    public void doSomething(){
        //...
    }
}
```

If you use

```
@Autowired
private A yourVariable;
```

you might be tempted to use the `doSomethingElse()` method that is an implementation detail (by what reason whatsoever).

However, if you use

```
@Qualifier("a")
private I yourVariable;
```

this cannot happen as the method is not present in the interface.

This gives you the ability to swap the implementation at any time.

Comment: Yeah, you just need to change the qualifier or the component name but not any other code.

Answer (score 0):

> Wouldn't it make more sense to autowire the class directly instead of interface?

This pretty much depends on how exactly do you work with qualifiers but in general, the answer is "No", autowiring the class is a bad thing to do if you have an interface - you should always work by interface.

Here are the examples:

```
interface I { void foo(); }
class IImpl1 implements I { 
  void foo() {System.out.println("Impl1");  
  pubic void bar() {// another method - why not?}
}
class IImpl2 implements I { void foo() {System.out.println("Impl2"); }
```

Note, that an implementation `IImpl1` has an additional method `bar` that doesn't belong to the interface `I`

Case 1:

```
@Component
public class Driver {
    @Autowired
    private IImpl1 i;
}
```

Here class Driver is tightly could to the concrete implementation `IImpl1` in general I can call method `bar` from the `Driver` class because I have this implementation, but in this case if I'll have to switch the implementation of `Driver` in future you'll have to also change the code: both change the reference, and also get rid of calls to `IImpl1.bar()` that might be not that easy to do - its a change in logic. As a result, the whole polymorphic behavior is lost.

By far its the worst way to program.

Now, consider Case 2:

```
@Component
public class Driver {
   
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("someLogicalName") // under the hood it spring will map it to IImpl1 but you don't know that here
   I i;
}
```

In this case - the things are much better - you never couple the driver to the concrete implementation at the level of code. This means that in general its enough to change the qualifier to get another implementation. You can't call `bar` anymore - it won't compile.
You also do not know what the implementation will be injected. If in future the implementation of the component that actually implements the logic of "someLogicalName" will change (by that I mean that you'll create a new class `IImpl3`), you won't feel it here - you'll place that qualifier on that new class and all the places that use it will get that implementation automatically.

Case 3:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public Driver driver(@Qualifier("someLogicalName") I i) {
       return new Driver(i);
   }
}

public class Driver {
   private final I i;

   public Driver(I i) { // in real life this constructor can be generated by 
                        // lombok or something, put it here for the sake of completeness
     this.i = i;
   }
}
```

This by far the most "clean" approach - conceptually its really similar to case 2, however in this case you don't place the qualifier at the level of `Driver` class at all, in fact, the class `Driver` is not even aware at the level of code / metadata that its related to Spring anyhow. Of course all the "advantages" of case 2 are also applicable here as well.